# How much washing up liquid do we ingest per year and how harmful is it?

Tags: detergent

When cleaning a bowl with washing up liquid, I notice that even after rinsing, bubbles still form on the surface. A trace of washing up liquid remains on the plate or cutlery.

We must ingest trace amounts of washing up liquid every day. We are literally eating detergent.

Now, I'm sure these products have all been tested etc. But what kind of health effects would the detergent cause to our insides?

Could it be, for example, that 1 out of a million deaths are actually caused by our ingestion of washing up liquid? Have there been any studies on this?

Edit: Also note that a lot of people don't adequately rinse as in [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2017/jul/26/washing-up-liquid-health-hazard).

Comment: Adequate rinsing really does remove all the soap, and water will form some bubbles all on its own. Are you sure of the premise of your question?

Comment: From my own experience I would disagree that it removes "all" washing up liquid (every single molecule of the 20 or so ingredients?). Where are the tests to show that? Definitely at least trace elements will remain. In fact it would be impossible to prove otherwise. In fact I would even add that a scientist would be able to tell which washing up liquid had been used if he needed to do so.

Comment: Unless of course you are defining adequately to mean washing off every single atom. In which case I can't argue with a tautology. But I would say in that case 100% of people don't "adequately" rinse.

Comment: Okay, fine. Your world is full of molecules, some of them quite deadly in sufficient quantity. Like, for example, oxygen.

Comment: The difference being we've evolved to ingest oxygen over millions of years. Whereas we haven't evolved to ingest man-made chemicals inside washing up liquid. And some traces of molecules are deadly even in tiny quantities.